# Consume Batches through Kafka in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm new to Kafka, Wanna enable processing in batches through the consumer.

Read through [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_consuming_batches) and found that Starting with version 3.0 we can enable batch processing.

Currently we are using `Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE` and below dependencies for kafka:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**What changes do I need to do in pom.xml before starting properties and code changes? Do i need to change Springboot version?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consume it as a batch with @StreamListener. You just need to give a deserializer. Example :

You just need to give a deserializer.

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    .........
}


   @StreamListener(value = PersonStream.INPUT)
    private void personBulkReceiver(List<Person> person) {
        System.out.println("personBulkReceiver : " + person.size());
    }


spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
      binders:
        bulkKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
                      configuration:
                        max.poll.records: 1500
                        fetch.min.bytes: 1000000
                        fetch.max.wait.ms: 10000
                        value.deserializer: tr.cloud.stream.examples.PersonDeserializer
      bindings:
        person-topic-in:
          binder: bulkKafka
          destination: person-topic
          contentType: application/person
          group : omercelik
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true

public class PersonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Person> {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You need Boot 2.3.1 and cloud Hoxton.SR6.</strike>

Batch mode is only supported with the functional programming style, not `@StreamListtener`.

**EDIT**

This works fine (using the preferred functional model) with current versions (Boot 2.7, cloud 2021.0.3) without any deserializer.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So627947721Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So627947721Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<List<Foo>> input() {
        return System.out::println;
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("input-in-0", "{\"bar\":\"baz\"}".getBytes());
            template.send("input-in-0", "{\"bar\":\"qux\"}".getBytes());
        };
    }

    public static class Foo {

        String bar;

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.consumer.batch-mode=true
```

```
[Foo [bar=baz], Foo [bar=qux]]
```

Comment: Is this blog leads to the wrong info? https://medium.com/@vijaya.cigala/consuming-messages-in-batch-mode-in-kafka-using-spring-cloud-stream-kafka-binder-28d782f979cc

Comment: You get no payload conversion; it will only work if you `useNativeDecoding` to convert the payload using a Kafka Deserializer.

Comment: Why do we need to give serializer when reading batch mode in @StreamListener? How was this state solved in functional programming style? Can you explain the logic of this? What is the difference between @StreamListener's batch mode and functional programming style's batch mode?@GaryRussell

Comment: This answer is very old; there have been a lot of changes since then; I have no recollection of why I made that statement. Also, it is never a good idea to ask supplemental questions in comments, given that software evolves over time. This works fine in batch mode with current versions (with no deserializer): `@Bean
public Consumer<List<Foo>> input() {
 return System.out::println;
}`  - see the edit.

Comment: Gary, I think you're talking about functional style. I'm still working with @StreamListener. And while consuming batch, I have to give deserializer. Why do I still need to give deserializer in @StreamListener?I can ask in a separate question if you want.

Comment: That code is deprecated and no longer enhanced; it will be removed in 4.0. It's a completely different code base to that used for the functional style. My best guess is that it just doesn't have logic to convert the payloads when the receiving method parameter is a `List` (doesn't have the smarts to look at the generic type, just the actual parameter type); hence the payloads have to be converted somewhere else (i.e. by the deserializer).

Comment: All right, Garry, thank you very much. I can delete my comments if you think it will cause confusion. Thank you again.

Comment: No; it is fine, it might help someone.